# How to understand if a record has been deleted?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, delete-record

I am using Laravel 5.1, how do I know when a record was successfully deleted?

```
public function destroy(news $news)
{
    $news->delete();
    return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `delete()` function returns a boolean if the operation was successful or not, the same way that `save()` and other DML related functions do.

So in this case to check if the record was successfully deleted you could test:

```
    if($news->delete())
       return response()->json(['success'=> true]);
    else
       return response()->json(['success'=> false]);
```